# How to get full spelling of month is using calender module in python pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, calendar

I have following table

```
NMonth    
01         
02
03
```

if i using following code(calender module)

```
SMonth=df['NMonth'].apply(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[x])
```

My result will be :

```
NMonth    SMonth
01         Jan
02         Feb
03         Mar
```

How to get the full spelling of the month if using calender module? below is my desire result

```
NMonth    SMonth
01         January
02         February
03         March
```

Comment: Why not just make your own dictionary for it?

Comment: Use `calendar.month_name`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `month_name` instead of `month_abbr`.

`SMonth = df['NMonth'].apply(lambda x: calendar.month_name[x])`

You could have found this answer yourself in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_name

Answer (score 1):

I think here is better use `map` by dictionary:

```
months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August',
          'September','October','November','December']

d = {'{:02d}'.format(i+1):months[i] for i in range(12)}
print (d)
{'05': 'May', '01': 'January', '06': 'June', '11': 'November', 
'04': 'April', '12': 'December', '09': 'September', '08': 'August', 
'03': 'March', '07': 'July', '10': 'October', '02': 'February'}

SMonth=df['NMonth'].map(d)
print (SMonth)

0     January
1    February
2       March
Name: NMonth, dtype: object
```

Comment: Only downside with this approach is that `calendar.month_name` automatically detects the current locale. This approach hard-codes the names.